# How to hide iframe src

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I noticed that all the Facebook applications that running inside an iframe hiding their iframe SRC, instead of the real src there is a "javascript:""".
How can i do that? I want that my iframe will hide the original src

thanks!

Comment: Facebook isn't "hiding" anything, and you shouldn't be trying to.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [is there a way hide elements in IFRAME src page?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27129487/is-there-a-way-hide-elements-in-iframe-src-page)

Comment: @Kevin Brown dude its a question from 2012.. Your suggest question is from 2014.. :/

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Facebook applications are loaded dynamically, which means the SRC is changed after the HTML is loaded. That is why you can only see `javascript:;`. The src is not hidden though, it is still there and can be obtained using javascript.

If you are using jQuery, you could use something like this:

```
<iframe src="javascript:;" id="myframe"></iframe>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#myframe').attr('src', 'http://facebook.com');
});
</script>
```

With this, the iframe will have `javascript:;` as src in the HTML, but will load `facebook.com`

Comment: I know that solution But if you inspecting the element you still can see the src is javascript:""" in facebook, with this solution I see the new src when I'm inspecting the iframe

Comment: Could you provide URL to an example page?

Comment: you could omit the src attribute like <iframe id="myframe"></iframe> and the script above will work anyways.

Comment: but URL is viable in jquery

Comment: @AseshaGeorge Of course it is, it's impossible to make it truly "invisible".

Answer (score 4):

Creat elem HTML:

```html
<div id="htmlTest"></div>
```

JS code:

```js
var blobMe= URL['createObjectURL'](new Blob([''], {type: 'text/html'}));
var elIframe = document['createElement']('iframe');
elIframe['setAttribute']('frameborder', '0');
elIframe['setAttribute']('width', '100%');
elIframe['setAttribute']('height', '500px');
elIframe['setAttribute']('allowfullscreen', 'true');
elIframe['setAttribute']('webkitallowfullscreen', 'true');
elIframe['setAttribute']('mozallowfullscreen', 'true');
elIframe['setAttribute']('src', blobMe);
var idOne= 'gepa_'+ Date.now();
elIframe['setAttribute']('id', idOne);
document.getElementById('htmlTest').appendChild(elIframe);
const iframeHere= 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/GdIEi4lIH_Q';
document['getElementById'](idOne)['contentWindow']['document'].write('<script type="text/javascript">location.href = "' + iframeHere + '";</script>')
```

---

Source:
https://www.nodejsauto.com/2020/08/iframe-where-src-what-is-blob.html

Comment: I used this in a Vue app and it worked, thanks

Answer (score 3):

You are misunderstanding what you are seeing.  Facebook is not "hiding" thi iframe src, it's just that the src is loaded via javascript.  It's quite easy to see the iframe by using IE Developer tools (F12) or Firebug, or the native google chrome inspectors.  There's nothing "hidden" about it, it just doesn't show up when you view source.