# is there a way hide elements in IFRAME src page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I have a very simple code. I like to hide some DIV's in my IFRAMe. So my index.html page looks like this, so the whole idea is hide the top and the leftpanel of from the Calendar.aspx page.

any idea what's wrong with my code or how should I do this?

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></<script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$( document ).ready(function() {
$("#leftpanel").hide();
$("#toppanel").hide
});
();
</script>
<iframe height="800px" width="800px"  src="https://domain/Calendar/Calendar%20Color%20Overview.aspx" >
</iframe>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can try this:

```
$('#iframeID').load(function(){
    $('#iframeID').contents().find('#leftpanel').hide();
    $('#iframeID').contents().find('#toppanel').hide();
});
```

Or:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#iframeID').contents().find('#leftpanel').hide();
    $('#iframeID').contents().find('#toppanel').hide();
});
```

This method is not possible if you want to work with different domains.

Comment: It would definitely require the usage of the `.contents()` method before you can work with `.find()`. But even then it won't do it if we have a SOP violation.

Comment: @jAndy, darn, forgot that part indeed. Will not work cross-domain, i edited my answer ;)

Comment: well it's company intranet site, I'm for the moment testing on my pc. so I added id=iframeID in <iframe tag and checked the find results it's returning object, but it doesn't hide.

Comment: @user3080110 it does not work when pulling the data from another domain. Therefor you need different approach check http://blog.cakemail.com/the-iframe-cross-domain-policy-problem/

Comment: it's clear so it's not working, thanks for the answer.

Comment: @deer: I now created the page in the same domain. but it still doesn't hide.

Comment: That's weird. Where do you put the code? In the page where the iframe is included or the file where the iframe is coming from?

Answer (score 1):

The `document` focuses on the current document and not the `<iframe>`. You need to go through its `content`s and find the elements before hiding them.

```
$('iframe').load(function() {
    $('iframe').contents().find('#leftpanel,#toppanel').hide();
});
```

Comment: I added this in the script it's not working. is it because of cross domain? the site is on our company intranet site.

Comment: For CORS (http://enable-cors.org/index.html) , on the iframe site, you can add `Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"` in a .htaccess file if you're using Apache.

Answer (score 0):

I achieved this by creating a hidden form that posts data to the iframe src then deletes itself onpageload. Left with a iframe with src(unknown).

I used post to send data to url. Need full control of target domain to receive request. Have not tried code with a GET request.

```
//html
<div id='deleteForm'>
<form style='display: none;' class='fakeForm' id='fakeForm' target="target_iframe" action="(iframe url)" method="post">
    //(optional) can send data to iframe src as a post request
    <input type="hidden" name='data' value="data you may want to send"/>
    <input type="submit" style='display: none;'>
</form>
</div>

<iframe id='target_iframe' src=''></iframe>

//js
window.onload = function () {
  var form = document.getElementById("fakeForm");
  form.submit();
  var deleteParent = document.getElementById("deleteForm");
  deleteParent.remove();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**NOTE : This demo was tested on chrome 88 so it is not warrantied to work on each browser** 
Absolutely yes you can hide iframe elements using plain js no need to use jquery for that. 
**This is the function that would do us the magic**

```
function myFunction() {
  var iframe = document.getElementById("myFrame");
  var elmnt = iframe.contentWindow.document.getElementsByTagName("tagYouWantFromIframe")[position];
  elmnt.style.display = "none";
}
```

**and here is how we use it**

- load the script in the html footer of your file
- insert `onload="myFunction()"` on your iframe, body tag, or a parent element of the iframe. but better if you just use the body or the iframe tag directly and we are done.

**practically**
see this link https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GOYQTYNRBFVH

Comment: Does not work on cross origin iframes you do not control. 
"Uncaught DOMException: Permission denied to access property "document" on cross-origin object"

Answer (score -5):

because you have a problem in script 
you should remove this sign" < "in the last of this script

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></<script>
```

it should be like this

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: No, this is not at all related to this question.