# Want to hide <a> tag inside iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

In my current project, I need to load iframe which is loaded through script tag.
In that iframe, one link is coming ( tag), so I want to hide that  tag. 
Possible?

I'm adding one widget to my site.

Below is my sample code:

```
    <script src='https://www.indianballot.com/js/widget2.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
```

This JS file is loading iframe through document.write();
Is there any way to hide that  tag ?

Comment: Is the iframe on the same domain?

Comment: You can only hide things by not putting them on the web

Comment: `Possible?`- Yes if in the same domain ► [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27129487/is-there-a-way-hide-elements-in-iframe-src-page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27129487/is-there-a-way-hide-elements-in-iframe-src-page) or load the content then hide the element ► [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30232738/hide-content-inside-iframe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30232738/hide-content-inside-iframe)

Comment: Please provide a little more code, like the content, which is loaded. I'm not certain yet, what exactly the problem is.

Comment: No, it's from other domain @ovokuro

Comment: @AkashThakkar not possible so

Comment: Ok @ovokuro, Thanks for answer.

Answer (score -1):

If your `src='JS File Source'` is a local file and you can edit the a tag in there then this would be a solution.  Alternatively you could use another bit of JS to find the a href when page has loaded and toggle visibility of it there.

Hope this helps

Comment: No, that file is not local. I am loading it from other site.